# Jumping into swift - trouble with array of dictionary from json

Tags: swift, dictionary, for-loop

json comes in and is an array of dictionary:

```
let dict = try JSONSerialization.dictionary(data: data, options: .allowFragments)


(key: contact_383348580, value: {
    email = "r@c.com";
    "first_name" = Jon;
    "last_name" = B;
    tags = "";
})
(key: contact_445575065, value: {
    email = "n.w@s.com";
    "first_name" = "<null>";
    "last_name" = "<null>";
    tags = "";
})
```

Trying to map this to a User class (and then sort alpha by first name(?)) and then populate a tableview.

I'm all obj-c but trying to add this feature in my objc project through swift to improve my skills incrementally. But googling returns all different ways with different swift versions that don't seem to work (or frankly make sense to me anyway but I'll get there).

Currently I can create users but the names are empty.

```
for objects in dict {
    print(objects)

    let first = dict["first_name"] as? String
    let last = dict["last_name"] as? String
    let name = "\(first ?? "asas") \(last ?? "sdasd")"
    let object = User(username: name)
    contacts.append(object!)
}
print(" contacts \(contacts)")
```

Comment: Also, avoid `.allowFragment` until you know what it allows really. Issues, the `objects` is not what you think it is, click with your mouse over it with alt, you'll see. Also, inside your for loop, you use `dict`, you meant  `objects`? Do `for (aKey, aValue) in dict { let first = aValue["firstName"]... }`?

Comment: Are you responsible for the server side? If yes, send a more reasonable format. An array of dictionaries containing only one item respectively is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: @vadian No control over server

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an array of dictionaries and if that is correct then you have fooled yourself with the naming of your variables because `dict` is an array and `objects` a dictionary. I assume your code doesn't compile?

What about this

```
let array = try JSONSerialization.dictionary(data: data, options: .allowFragments)

for dict in array {
    let first = dict["first_name"] as? String ?? "asas"
    let last = dict["last_name"] as? String ?? "sdasd"
    let name = "\(first) \(last)"
    let object = User(username: name)
    contacts.append(object)
}
```